# Publish DLL files FTP in NetCore

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, ftp, publish

Im starting development in NetCore, and I just figurate that I cant upload in visual studio only one .dll file via FTP becouse NetCore publish the .dll files in the root of the folder and in the solution they are in */bin/debug/xxx.dll* so its returns me an invalid path exception.

Steps:

1. Open net core solution Expand the big/debug/ folder,
2. Right click over one dll file
3. Select Publish (via Ftp to the server path)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wcSd.png)